# Sencha GXT3 - Grid Column Header: Doubleclick Handler between two column headers

Tags: gwt, grid, handler, gxt

I have the following problem:

customer wants Excel like behaviour on a table. When double-clicking on the space between two column-headers, the column should be sized like the biggest text inside that column.

**Question:** Is there a build in GXT function to add a Handler to the space between two column headers? I havent found sth. like that, browsing the documentation of grid...

Additional Information: GXT: 3.0.1 GWT: 2.5.1

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't seem GXT exposes any handlers for actions on the column separators. A possible solution would be to have a option in the column drop down. There is an aricle about that here: http://greatlogic.com/2014/06/02/autofit-column-width-in-a-gxt-grid/

Comment: Thank you so much. I Lost all hope that anyone would ever see my post. I thought, if there is an oportunity to grab the space between two columns, there must be any kind of handler.

Comment: My pleasure. It would make sense that you could attached to that but doesn't seem to be exposed in the component. It seems all the logic for that happens purely in the JS. Hope you find a way around it.